# How to check a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my input:

```
<input name="my_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

I'm trying to check/uncheck it via jquery:

```
this._holder.find('checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

But this fails to work. I know this._holder.find is working as I am able to set this:

```
this._holder.find('input').val('whatever');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.find('checkbox')` checkbox is not an element

Comment: CSS selectors 101 `"checkbox"` is looking for  `<checkbox></checkbox>` That is an element selector, not an attribute selector.

Comment: this question is duplicate of hundreds of others... I don't mean to be rude, but did you even try googling this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery/426276#426276

Answer (score 1):

Your selector doesn't work because your element hasn't `checkbox` as tag.

Use

```
this._holder.find('[name=my_checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
this._holder.find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: should be `type` rather than `name`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox").prop('checked',true);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj3u2oyf/)